# SSL Exception Issue - With few WIFI AP

Tags: android, security, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

In one of the Android App installed on Google Pixel 7, I see SSL Exception issue mentioned below:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

**Query:**
Observed this error with the app only when connected to particular WIFI AP.  Example:

- WIFI AP1 - SSL Exception Issue Observed.
- WIFI AP2 - SSL Exception Issue Not Observed.

1. Does this indicate the error is with my WIFI AP or Android App side?
2. Why the behaviour is different with WIFI AP?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What type of Wifi networks are we talking about, personal/private, free/public or company owned Wifi APs? Usually the error `Trust anchor for certification path not found` occurs when the site uses a self-signed certificate but as it changes with the used Wifi network this might be an indicator that the Wifi is configured to intercept SSL/TLS traffic to get access to the unencrypted data inside the TLS protected channel.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Its company owned WIFI APs. Sorry I could not get your below comment, could you help to elaborate on it: "Wifi is configured to intercept SSL/TLS traffic to get access to the unencrypted data inside the TLS protected channel".. Do you mean app with WIFI AP not throwing the SSL exception is accessing unencrypted data ?

Comment: There is likely a corporate proxy doing SSL interception - see [How does SSL Proxy server in company work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/how-does-ssl-proxy-server-in-company-work).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. So do you have any suggestion how can i fix this issue i.e. different behaviour with different WIFI AP? Do i need to fix it from Android App side so that behaviour can be consistent?

Comment: You need to import the CA certificate used by the corporate proxy as trusted in your system. This will allow man in the middle by the corporate proxy though - not sure if you want this. And it will not work if the app uses certificate or public key pinning. The other alternative is to ask your IT admins for an exception for this specific target domain the app uses.